# Using pst-solides3d to cut an object multiple times

Tags: 3d, pst-solides3d

Using [`pst-solides3d`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d) I can draw the following half-torus (a full torus cut along the plane y = 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{filecontents}{process_ghostscript.txt}
\end{filecontents}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psset{
    viewpoint=10 10 10,lightsrc=viewpoint,
    Decran=25,
    solidmemory
  }

  \psSolid[%
    object=tore,r0=1,r1=3,
    plansepare={[0 1 0 0]},% Plane y = 0
    %plansepare={[-1 0 0 0]},% Plane x = 0
    fillcolor=red!50!white,incolor=green,
    name=torusA,
    grid,ngrid=15 30,
    hollow=true,
    action=draw**
  ](0,0,0)%

  \axesIIID(0,0,0)(1,1,1)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Cutting along the plane x = 0 is achieved by replacing the cutting plane (or `plansepare`) with `plansepare={[-1 0 0 0]}`:

[image]

However, I'd like to combine this, cutting the torus along both planes x = 0 and y = 0 and leaving only a quarter-torus. I followed the approach contained within the [`pst-solides3d` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) under the section **Slicing a hollow solid**, specifically **The second slice and its insertion within the pyramid** where an object (a pyramid) is sliced twice. I thought this would work but didn't:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psset{
    viewpoint=10 10 10,lightsrc=viewpoint,
    Decran=25,
    solidmemory
  }
  % Create the first half-torus
  \psSolid[%
    object=tore,r0=1,r1=3,
    plansepare={[0 1 0 0]},% Plane y = 0
    fillcolor=red!50!white,incolor=green,
    name=torusA,
    grid,ngrid=15 30,
    hollow=true,
    action=none
  ](0,0,0)%

  % Load torusA0 and slice it gain
  \psSolid[%
    object=load,load=torusA0,
    plansepare={[-1 0 0 0]},% Plane x = 0
    fillcolor=red!50!white,incolor=green,
    name=torusB,
    grid,ngrid=15 30,
    hollow=true,
    action=draw**
  ](0,0,0)%

  \axesIIID(0,0,0)(1,1,1)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Moreover, `hollow=true` seems to be ignored.

---

**Note:** One can obtain a quarter torus via a parametric surface equation using

```
  \defFunction[algebraic]{torus}(u,v)
    {(3 + 1*cos(u))*cos(v)}% x
    {(3 + 1*cos(u))*sin(v)}% y
    {1*sin(u)}% z
  \psSolid[
    object=surfaceparametree,grid,
    base=0 2 pi mul neg pi 2 div pi,
    fillcolor=red!50!white,incolor=green,
    function=torus,
    ngrid=15 30
  ](0,0,0)
```

[image]

However, this is not what I'm after. The plane cuts mentioned above are simple/ordinary (along the axes). In general I'd not cut this way, but along some generic plane ax + by + cz + d = 0.

Comment: Oh, you never received an answer?!